# Ruby and class variables in inherit class

Tags: ruby, class-variables

```
class A
  def set(v)
    @@v = v
  end
  def put
    puts @@v
  end
end

class B < A
end
class C < A
end

B.new.set 'b'
B.new.put # => b
C.new.set 'c'
C.new.put # => c
B.new.put # => c
```

Why? And how should I write this to have 'b' in last B.new.put?

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want instance variables? (e.g. @v, instead of @@v)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a nice article on the subject - [Class and Instance Variables In Ruby](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/).

Basically, what you can do is:

```
class A
  class << self
    attr_accessor :class_var
  end

  def set_class_var(value)
    self.class.class_var = value
  end

  def get_class_var
    self.class.class_var
  end
end

class B < A; end

A.class_var = 'a'
B.class_var = 'b'
puts A.class_var # => a
puts B.class_var # => b

A.new.set_class_var 'aa'
B.new.set_class_var 'bb'
puts A.new.get_class_var # => aa
puts B.new.get_class_var # => bb
```

To understand it you should think about `A` as an instance of `Class` class (and that's how it is in Ruby). But every object in Ruby has its own singleton class that stores object-specific stuff like methods defined on object itself:

```
a = A.new
def a.foo
  puts 'foo'
end
```

In that case `foo` is method defined only for `a` object and not for every instance of `A` class. And another way to define method in object's singleton class is like that:

```
class << a # open a's singleton class
  def bar  # define method that will be available only on 'a' object
    puts 'bar'
  end
end
```

In the first code snippet we use that approach to define `class_var` attribute accessor in the context of singleton class of our `A` class (it's a bit tricky, so you need to think about it). As the result class itself has `class_var` variable as well as its descendant class `B`. The difference is that every one of them has its own `class_var` variable that do not interfere.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to pull out [`class_inheritable_accessor` code](http://apidock.com/rails/Class/class_inheritable_accessor) from Rails and include its behavior in your classes. See [here](http://www.raulparolari.com/Rails/class_inheritable) for a good discussion and the guts of the code.

Perhaps you don't really want a class variable, though.

Comment: @Ximik No problem. It's basically an extensible, hierarchical version of KL-7's answer;

Answer (score -1):

Assigning a value to a class variable (an @@ variable) sets it for EVERY instance of the class.  It even "sets" it for instances that "aren't created yet."  So, consider this...

```
B.new.set 'b' # OK, that set @@v for that particular instance of B

B.new.put # Hey, you just created *another* new instance of B!
```

How can @@v have a value in that one?  The second object's value of @@v would be unset, *except* for the fact that @@v is a **class variable**, so it has the same value for **every** instance of the class.

Comment: The real problem here is that class variable in Ruby is actually class-hierarchy variable. The class shares his class variables with all his descendants.