# Declaring static properties of Rails model subclasses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sti

I'm new to Ruby and Rails (and programming!), and trying to figure out the idiomatic way of passing properties from a model to its STI children.

I have a generic model 'Document', and some models that inherit from it — let's take 'Tutorial' as the example. I have a string field for an 'icon', in which I want to store the icon's filename but not full path (I think the path should be up to each model, as it's a detail of retrieving the record's data?):

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :body, :icon

  @@asset_domain = "http://assets.example.com/"
  @@asset_path = "documents/"

  def icon
    @@asset_domain.to_s + @@asset_path.to_s + read_attribute(:icon).to_s
  end
end
```

This is the kind of thing I'd like to do with the subclasses, so they look for their 'icons' (or any other asset) in an appropriate place.

```
class Tutorial < Document
  attr_accessible :title, :body, :icon

  @@asset_path = "tutorials/"

  # Other tutorial-only stuff
end
```

I've read about class variables and understand why what I've written above didn't work quite as I intended, but what's the best way of overriding 'asset_path' in the Tutorial class? I don't think I should use instance variables as the values don't need to change per instance of the model. Any ideas much appreciated (even if it means rethinking it!)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251352/ruby-inherit-code-that-works-with-class-variables

Comment: are you planning to change those values ever or are they really constants?

Comment: This is the one I was looking for. But I agree with jstim--and the first referenced SO post hints that they're more like constants anyway. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369050/ruby-and-class-variables-in-inherit-class/8369249#8369249

Comment: Thanks for the link Dave — yes I should definitely be using a constant for the `asset_domain` and I now have some ideas about how to state the `asset_path`. Great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to create a constant value that you can reuse to build paths. Instead of using a class variable, I would use a constant.

Now the question of placement:

### In-Class

If it really only needs to be used in `Document` and the classes that inherit from it, define a constant at the top of the stack:

```
# document.rb
#
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :body, :icon

  ASSET_DOMAIN = "http://assets.example.com/"

end
```

This would be accessible in `Document` `Tutorial` and other objects that inherit from those.

### Environment.rb

If this is a value you are going to use **everywhere**, what about adding a constant to your `environment.rb`? That way you don't have to remember to redefine it in all the classes you placed it.

```
# environment.rb
#
# other config info
#
ASSET_DOMAIN = "http://assets.example.com/"
```

And then you could build links wherever you like and not be constrained by Class:

```
# documents.rb
#
icon_path = ASSET_DOMAIN + path_and_file

# tutorial.rb
#
icon_path = ASSET_DOMAIN + path_and_file

# non_document_model.rb
#
icon_path = ASSET_DOMAIN + path_and_file
```

This may be editorializing, but rubyists seem to cringe when they see `@@`. There's a time and place, but for the kind of thing you want to do I would use a constant and decide where you need to place it.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. You're right actually, the asset domain does have a broader scope than just my `Documents`.

And it's an inherent app setting that I should be able to change easily, so putting a constant in `environment.rb` makes perfect sense. (Say if assets.example.com breaks and I need to use assets.example2.com, I just change it there and redeploy — easy!).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply override the `icon` function from `Document` in `Tutorial` (as it inherits from it) and have it return the correct path.

This is a classic case of [Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming) in object-oriented programming. An example:

```
class Document
  attr_accessor :title, :body, :icon

  ASSET_DOMAIN = "http://assets.example.com/"

  def icon
    return ASSET_DOMAIN + "documents/" + "document_icon.png"
  end
end

class Tutorial < Document
  def icon
    return ASSET_DOMAIN + "tutorials/" + "tutorial_icon.png"
  end
end

d = Document.new
puts d.icon

i = Tutorial.new
puts i.icon
```

Output:

```
http://assets.example.com/documents/document_icon.png
http://assets.example.com/tutorials/tutorial_icon.png
```

Note because `Tutorial` is a **subclass** of `Document`, it inherits both its fields and its methods. Therefore `:title`, `:body` and `:icon` do not need to be redefined within `Tutorial` and the `icon` method can be redefined to give the desired output. It's also wise to store a value that will rarely change in a constant, `ASSET_DOMAIN` in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer on the `asset_path` part of the question. I'm going to do what you suggest and override the `icon` accessor method in each child class (as there aren't many), but it does seem a bit redundant to keep reimplementing the method? Say I change my folder structure on `assets.example.com`. I have to tell each class (rather than just the `Document`) how to form a path for the new structure. I'm actually leaning more towards a _convention over configuration_ approach of taking the class name as the path name...